# Troubleshooting Next.js Image Rendering Issue with DALL-E API Generated Images

Tags: reactjs, next.js, openai-api

I'm currently working on an app that utilizes DALL-E's API to generate images, which are then saved as URLs in my database. For the most part, everything seems to be working as expected. However, I've encountered a persistent issue that I could use some help with.

When I click on one of the saved images, the app redirects me to a separate page with a file structure like "dashboard/[id]/page.tsx". On this page, I'm trying to display the image using the Next.js Imagecomponent. Strangely, despite the correct URL being present and accessible, I keep encountering the following error: "ImageError: 'URL' parameter is valid, but upstream response is invalid."

The peculiar part is that even though the image is present in the designated location, it only shows a placeholder image and not the actual image content. This leads me to wonder whether the issue lies with Next.js or if there might be a problem with my code structure.

Has anyone else encountered a similar problem or can offer any insights into how I might resolve this issue? I've been trying to debug the situation but could use some fresh perspectives on the matter. Thanks in advance for any guidance you can provide!

Code:

```
import { PageWrapper } from '@/components/Page-Wrapper';
import { db } from '@/lib/db';
import { ChevronLeft } from 'lucide-react';
import Image from 'next/image';

interface PageProps {
  id: string;
}

const page = async ({ id }: PageProps) => {
  const fetchSingleLogo = await db.image.findFirst({
    where: {
      id: id,
    },
    include: {
      user: true,
    },
  });

  if (!fetchSingleLogo) {
    return (
      <div className='flex flex-col justify-center items-center h-screen'>
        <p className='text-gray-600 text-lg'>Logo not found.</p>
      </div>
    );
  }

  return (
    <PageWrapper>
    <div className='flex flex-col h-screen'>
      <div className='p-4'>
        <a href='/dashboard' className='text-gray-600 hover:text-gray-800'>
          <ChevronLeft className='inline-block mr-1' />
          Go Back
        </a>
      </div>
      <div className='flex flex-col justify-center items-center h-full'>
        <h1 className='text-2xl md:text-4xl lg:text-5xl font-bold mb-4 text-gray-800'>
          Logo Details
        </h1>
        <div className='mt-6 rounded-lg shadow-lg overflow-hidden'>
          <Image
            src={fetchSingleLogo.url}
            className='w-full h-auto'
            width={500}
            height={500}
            alt='Your generated logo'
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </PageWrapper>
  );
};

export default page;
```

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M9UpK.png)

[Error link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6MB1Z.png)